# Ignore empty ComboBoxItems

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, observablecollection

I have a ComboBox which has bounded items, like

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list}"
          DisplayMemberPath="name"
          SelectedValuePath="id"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The Problem is that there is a minimum of 10 items in the `list` which can be empty.

**Is there a way to ignore empty values as items?**

---

I tried to remove the empty values with different methods, like

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
public ObservableCollection<myclass> list
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<myclass> list = new ObservableCollection<myclass>();

        foreach (var item in org_list.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.name)).ToList())
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't update the ComboBox any more if I'm adding any items to `org_list`.

Comment: Every time you add an item to org_list add it to list as well if the item is not empty. Or simply raise a property changed notification for list property whenever you add items to org_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mirror list which exposes the list without the empties. For changes subscribe to the observable collections events that are relevant such as add/remove and keep the mirror consistent. Then bind to this filtered list.